# Is it possible to use add_periodic_timer with subsecond ticks?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

Using EventMachine with Ruby, is it possible to do 0.5 seconds? Or 0.01?

The docs all say 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following

```
require 'eventmachine'

Thread.new { EM::run}
while !EM.reactor_running? ; end

EM::add_periodic_timer(0.01) { puts "#{Time.now.to_f}" }
sleep
```

you can check the displayed numbers and verify that the difference of two consecutive ones are really close to the duration you specified to `EM::add_periodic_timer`. On my home pc with almost 0 load I can go down to 0.001 seconds without any problems.

Comment: I'm going to assume this solved it, but the docs definitely weren't clear. (I moved away from using event machine).